# FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile not uploading to my current Java directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jsp, file-upload

I'm making a web app and I'm in the process of uploading a picture for one of my form. The file got uploaded however it got copied into my mac eclipse installation folder instead of my current java directory.

Part of the code is as below.

```
            Part filePart = request.getPart("poster");
            String fileName = getFileName(filePart);
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

            File targetFile = new File ("temp/"+fileName);
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fileContent, targetFile);
```

How can I copy via FileUtils into my current directory?

I have search around and have yet to find a concrete answer and no matter what I try, it keeps getting uploaded into the eclipse.app contents folder in my mac.

Comment: Well, make sure `targetFile` contains the path of the directory you want to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file got uploaded however it got copied into my mac eclipse installation folder instead of my current java directory.

I take it that you are running the code from within Eclipse.  By default, an Eclipse Java launcher starts applications with the "current directory" set to the parent project's project directory.  If you want the current directory to be something else, you need to specify this in the launch configuration.

(When you run a Java application from the command line, the current directory should be what you expect ...)

Comment: Hi Stephen, Yes I'm running within Eclipse. Will it cause any issue if say I change it in launch configuration? or is there a another way of doing it?

Comment: 1)  No.  2)  Use an absolute pathname, or run the application from the command line.

Comment: Thank you so so very much! This helps me a lot! I've been looking around for solution for hours! This solve it! AWESOME. MANY MANY THANKS ONCE AGAIN!